# Particles.js pero para Angular 15?

Tags: angular

Muy buenas, Quisiera saber si existe algo parecido a Particles.js para Angular 15 (15.2.7), ya que cuando trato de instalar dicho framework, me dice soporta versiones anteriores a angular 13.
Tengo entendido que es un problema de dependencias...
Trate con varios "particles" pero ninguno se logra instalar.

La cosa es que ya comencé el proyecto y tengo miedo de volver a otra instancia de dependencias (Por ejemplo Angular 13) y que el resto de mi proyecto no funcione.

Comment: [tsParticles - TypeScript Particles](https://github.com/matteobruni/tsparticles)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Muy útil.